# A faster way needed to render a UIView hierarchy to an image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, core-graphics

I am trying to produce a video of a portion of my iOS app's UI. I can't use the screen recording APIs because I'm not capturing the entire screen, and also I'm rendering to a different dimension than what is displayed onscreen.

I currently am using the following code, which works:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outlineFrame.size, YES, 1.0);
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.outline.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

I then use AVFoundation APIs to encode the video. So, what's the problem?

It nearly pegs the CPU. It runs at 89% continuously on the fastest iPad currently available (iPad Pro 11"). And I'm currently rendering at 3 FPS.

**The bottleneck is color management.** I have profiled with instruments, and all signs point to Apple's color management as the culprit. And, Apple provides no way for us to turn off color management.

*On an iPad Air 2, the frameworks disable color management behind the scenes, and the code takes 20% CPU.*

### What I have tried

I have tried creating a CGBitmapContext myself and using different color spaces, to no avail. I've tried using `[view.layer renderInContext:context];` instead, but that does not produce good results; it does not clip offscreen views, and it does not include content rendered by OpenGL.

**BUT...** Core Animation does seem to not perform color management, and as a result, performs much better.

### The goal

I just want my views rendered to an image in a reasonably efficient way. I'll take anything I can get. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "a different dimension than what is displayed on screen," but as long as it's a subset of what's on screen, and at no higher resolution than that, you can still use ReplayKit. Use `startCapture` and in the callback you'll get raw SampleBuffers that you can crop or resize as you need.

Comment: Different resolution with a different aspect ratio. Edit: and stretching to fit is a bad idea for the type of content I'm sending.

Comment: Double checked, and I can alter things so that no stretching is needed. I am investigating use of ReplayKit.